# Using a loop to change schema of tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question about using a loop to change schema of tables in a SQL Server database.

This code is failing due to an error and I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

The error is:

> *Error: Incorrect syntax near '|'.*

And here is the T-SQL code is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
Into   #Temp 
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Declare @Name varchar2
Declare @mQuery varchar2

While (Select Count(*) From #Temp) > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 @Name = Name From #Temp;

    SET @mQuery = 'ALTER SCHEMA schema1 TRANSFER schema99.'  || @Name  ||  ';' ;

    dbms_output.put_line( @mQuery );

    --sp_executesql @mQuery;

    Delete #Temp Where Name = @Name;

End
```

Comment: SQL-Server's procedural language is **T-SQL** (Transact-SQL) - **not** PL/SQL (that's Oracle's language) - updated post and tags. And T-SQL uses **`+`** for string concatenation. [You could check that in the **extensive** SQL Server Books Online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PRINT` instead of `dbms_output.put_line`, and `+` instead of `||`:

```
SET @mQuery = 'ALTER SCHEMA schema1 TRANSFER schema99.'  + @Name  +  ';' ;

PRINT @mQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation in tsql is `+`, not `||`.